# Is there such a thing as an algorithm that runs in asymptotic time?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

For example: $O(-e^{-x} +1)$. Basically as the size of the input increases, the time it takes to run converges.

Comment: I have no idea what the question is; title and body seem not to match.

Answer (score 3):

It is not hard to see that $O(-e^{-x} +1) = O(1)$.